# SwitchCompat setTextOn() and setTextOff() doesn't work on runtime

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, switchcompat

I've tried to set the text on `SwitchCompat`, but it doesn't work. It only work for the first time. But when you tried to change the text (eg. when button is clicked), it doesn't work.

For example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.switch_test);
    switchCompat.setTextOn("Yes");
    switchCompat.setTextOff("No");
    switchCompat.setShowText(true);

    Button buttonTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switchCompat.setTextOn("YOO");
            switchCompat.setTextOff("NAH");
            //switchCompat.requestLayout();  //tried to this but has no effect
            //switchCompat.invalidate();     //tried to this but has no effect
        }
    });
}
```

You will see that the text stays as **Yes** and **No**. I've tried to call `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` with no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that `SwitchCompat` is not designed with that case in mind. It has private fields `mOnLayout` and `mOffLayout`, which are computed once and [not recomputed later](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.java#L798) when text is being changed.

So, you have to explicitly null them out in order text change to initiate those layouts to be recreated.

```
    buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
          Field mOnLayout = SwitchCompat.class.getDeclaredField("mOnLayout");
          Field mOffLayout = SwitchCompat.class.getDeclaredField("mOffLayout");

          mOnLayout.setAccessible(true);
          mOffLayout.setAccessible(true);

          mOnLayout.set(switchCompat, null);
          mOffLayout.set(switchCompat, null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        switchCompat.setTextOn("YOO");
        switchCompat.setTextOff("NAH");

      }
    });
```

Result:

[image]